# Data from json gets undefined

Tags: javascript, json

Im getting data in my .json file

```
{
  "types": [
    {
      "type": "Lotofácil",
    },
]
}
```

in the console.log(data) i get all the data in the .json
but data.types.type only gets "Undefined" in the html

```
var getJSON = function (url, callback) {
  var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhr.open('GET', url, true);
  xhr.responseType = 'json';
  xhr.onreadystatechange = function () {
    var status = xhr.status;
    if (status === 200) {
      callback(null, xhr.response);
    } else {
      callback(status, xhr.response);
    }
  };
  xhr.send();
};

getJSON('games.json', function (err, data) {
  if (err !== null) {
    console.log('Ocorreu um erro' + err);
  } else {
    var bets = document.getElementById('bets-container-lotos');
    bets.innerHTML = '';
    bets.innerHTML +=
      '<button class="bets-lotofacil" onclick=lotofacil()>' +
      data.types.type +
      '</button>';
    console.log(data);
  }
});
```

Comment: Why not drop the 20th century `XMLHttpRequest` syntax and use Fetch? `const response = await fetch(url); const data = await response.json();` job done. You don't even need a callback function or anything

Comment: Did you mean `data.types[0].type`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `types` property is an `array`,

you need to choose an item of the `array` before you can access the item's properties.

```js
let data = {
  "types": [{
    "type": "Lotofácil",
  }, ]
}

console.log(data.types[0].type)
```

Answer (score 1):

According to your JSON example, `data.types` is an array of objects (with `.type` fields), not an actual object.

You either want to use `data.types[0].type` to get the type of the first element, or map over `data.types` or similar.